# How can I ask for a salary renegotiation without seeming ungrateful?

Tags: communication, salary, raise

I'd like to renegotiate my salary at work, but I'm concerned about coming across as ungrateful.  My company has done a lot for me, including paying for me to take classes (costing them ~7k) and giving me a substantial raise (percentage-wise) in my last performance review.  Having gone from essentially a data entry position to overseeing two development projects without a large salary increase, however, I do feel that I add more value to the company than my salary reflects.

How can I discuss a salary increase with my boss while also acknowledging how much they've done for me already?

Also, if you don't feel that it's appropriate for me to ask for a raise in these circumstances, please feel free to say so.

Comment: 1. Just because you are doing something does not mean that your projects are getting completed successfully; 2. " I do feel that I add more value to the company than my salary reflects" What is the basis of "I feel", aside from it's a feeling, that is?

Comment: Well, the projects I've led have delivered successful products.  I've gotten good feedback on all of the work I've done, and my work brings money to the company.

Comment: Does your work bring more money to the company than others being paid the same?

Comment: It's a small company, and I'm the lowest paid employee.  There's no one else who does exactly what I do, but people doing comparable work to me get paid a higher salary.

Comment: Have you read any of the suggestions on how to ask for a raise and found recommendations that make you sound ungrateful? Seems like a good strategy would never sound ungrateful, but you still use valid reasons to justify a raise.

Comment: Yes I read them.  I think I may have worded the question poorly.  I meant something more like how to ask for a raise while explicitly acknowledging that the company has already given me a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I discuss a salary increase with my boss while also
>   acknowledging how much they've done for me already?

How about something along the lines of the following, during a 1-on-1 session between you and your boss:

> "Hey boss, I've been meaning to talk with you about something.
>
> I truly appreciate all that this company has done a lot for me,
>   including paying for me to take classes and giving me a substantial
>   raise in my last performance review.
>
> I really enjoy working here, and really like working with you.
>
> I've gone from essentially a data entry position to overseeing two
>   development projects without a large salary increase, and yet I feel
>   that I add more value to the company than my salary currently
>   reflects.
>
> I'd like to get a raise. What can I do to make that happen?"

Then take it from there and see what kind of response you get.

This basically expresses your gratitude explicitly, while also asking for more money.

Note that you have indicated you already got a "substantial raise", yet you also say that you've gone "without a large salary increase". To me that's confusing - substantial but not large? You probably want to clean up that line of thinking a bit before your discussion.

You also haven't indicated where you are on the salary range for others in your role (perhaps within your company, or within your industry and in your locale). You may already be right where you should be, or you may be significantly under where you should be. Knowing more about that could strengthen your argument.

And of course, enter the discussion being prepared in case the response is "No". Decide in your own head what your next step will be (nothing? look elsewhere? quit immediately?). I don't suggest anything rash - just that you have considered all the possibilities.